Database inspector in Android Studio is not showing when I connect my device and run my application
Database Inspector is not working on my device with API level more than 26 since somedays earlier it was working perfectly. I tried everything that is available over internet, but nothing is helping for me.
I tried to restart, invalidate cashes in android studio, disconnecting and connecting again, revoking USB debugging and enabling again nothing is working. When I try with an emulator or other device it works but something is seriously wrong with my device.
App inspection image

Are you sure that you have not deployed a "release" variant to this device? May be make sure that the active build variant is a "debug" build which can be selected from the build menu and then select re-launch a debug instance on this device.
